# User Controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, controls

I have a user control on a web page . I want to use the values of the web page on my web user control.How can i do this

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking of using page values in code i-e on server side , then you can access the page properties by casting the "this.Ownerpage" property of user control , and if you are talking of it on client side , then using Javascript/Jquery in combination with hidden fields you can do it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and set property in your user control:

```
private string m_name = string.Empty;
public string UserName()
{
    return TextBox.Text;
}
```

Then in your ASP.NET page you can access this property by:

```
MyUserControl.UserName();
```

Comment: +1 This is more clean and will let you avoid using the keyword "this"

Comment: @sumit: Adjust the code. The word after return ("TextBox") has to match the ID of your TextBox

Comment: What is the purpose for using m_name ?